# Can you hire an hireling in order to produce things for you?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, downtime

According to [downtime rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/downtime/), you can spend a day and pay half of the gold normally necessary to buy labor or goods if you do unskilled work.

Is it possible to hire untrained hireling and have them put the work so that you can spend 10 gold and 1 silver gaining labor or goods instead of spending 20 gold?

PS: I am talking about labor and goods (*Capital*) you normally use in order to create buildings in the downtime rules.

Comment: Should this question be "Can I apply "Downtime" rules to NPC hirelings?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible

Those rules were written with players in mind, but since you *are* allowed to hire people, using those same rules, you could get them to produce *Capital* for you.

> Earnings: This entry indicates what bonuses the room or team gives to its building’s or organization’s checks made to generate capital. Buildings and organizations act like characters in that **they can attempt a check each day to earn capital** performing skilled work (without costing you any downtime). You must pay for capital earned in this way as normal.

You would have to use the cost of **Laborers** though, since hiring that kind of worker is previewed in the rules, not hiring the generic unskilled worker from the [hirelings&services rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/hirelings-servants-services).

> Laborers
>
> Earnings gp or Labor +2
>
> **Create 1 Influence, 2 Labor (70 gp)**; Time 0 days; Size 5 people

This is a one time cost though, instead of a tax on every Capital earned. It may also be reduced in half if you earn that capital instead of paying the full cost.

Also, to clarify on this:

> you can spend a day and pay half of the gold normally necessary to buy labor or goods if you do **unskilled work**.

Maybe it isn't clear, but paying half the Capital cost (10g instead of 20g for Goods, for instance) is called *Earning Capital*, and that may be done **both skilled and unskilled**.